# Adding aria-label to angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, jaws-screen-reader

I've built a star rating component that I would like to add a description to for screen readers like JAWS to read on tab. Right now, when I test this with JAWS there is no description being read (ideally it should read the rating for the user). How do I add aria-labels to angular components?

star-rating.component.ts

```
<div [attr.aria-label]="'the rating is' + {{rating}} + 'out of' + {{starAmount}} + 'stars'">
    <app-star 
    *ngFor="let star of stars; let i = index"
    [rating]="rating"
    [starAmount]="starAmount">
    </app-star>
<div>
```

star-rating.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-star-rating",
  templateUrl: "./star-rating.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./star-rating.component.css"]
})
export class StarRatingComponent {
  @Input() starAmount;
  @Input() rating;
  total;
  Arr = Array;


}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is something wrong with your `aria-label` in the `div`: as you use an Angular input (`[attr.aria-label]`), the value is already Javascript. So you don't need to use `{{ }}` in there.

The following line should work:

`[attr.aria-label]="'the rating is ' + rating + ' out of ' + starAmount + ' stars'"`

I wonder, why you didn't get any errors from Angular in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In my case both NVDA and JAWS the screen readers reads from below semantic as such as with taking conditional values shown below

```
[attr.aria-label]="((client.issbInstalled)? 'Secure Browser is installed' :
 'Secure Browser is not installed ') + 'with' + index + client?.clientHostName"
```

OR

```
[attr.aria-label]="{
 true:'Secure Browser is installed with' + client?.clientHostName, 
 false: 'Secure Browser is not installed with' + client?.clientHostName
}[client.issbInstalled]"
```